# Metamask provider not detected on mobile

Tags: metamask, web3-providers

I have build a webapp to MINT our ERC721 token using Webflow. It works fine on desktop but the window.ethereum is never injected on mobile (browsers & metamask application)
Here is my code to detect the provider:

```
  detectEthereumProvider().then((result) => {
    if (result) {
      web3 = new Web3(result);
      handleEthereum(result);
    } else {
      setupOnboarding();
    }
  }).catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
```

On mobile setupOnboarding(); is always called as window.ethereum doesn't seem to be injected.
Mobile is Android 10 Huawei P30. Tested Chrome, Android & Metamask in-app browser. There is no CSP set for the website, CORS is set to strict-origin-when-cross-origin (cannot change it).

I've tested the same mobile on pancakeswap, it works in Metamask in-app browser but not Chrome (provider not found when clicking Metamask).

Any help would be appreciated I've been stuck on this :(

Comment: I am doing something similar but I cannot connect my token with metamask from the mobile, can you help me please

Comment: Did You Resolve ? You show how to make it work im stuck on that too. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The website was behind temporary Webflow auth to keep it from prying eyes, so just dropped the auth and it worked :)